# How to enable redirect with type push in next-intl

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-intl

I am using next-intl with Next.js 13 in a server action, and I want to redirect the user to another page using redirect from next-intl/server. However, I want to maintain browser history. Unfortunately, the redirect function in this library does not have a type option to specify whether it should be a push or replace action. How can I achieve a push-type redirect using this library on the server side?

does anyone have any alternative or can we do something with this?

Answer (score 0):

one option is to use the 'router.push' method from next/router of the redirect function from next-intl/server.this method allows you to specify the type of transition to push or replace. for a example tou can do something like this.

```
import{ useRouter } from 'mext/router'

export defalt function Mypage() {
const router = useRouter()

//.....

//Redirect to another pagewith push type
router.push('another-page', undefined, {locate: 'fr', type: 'push' })
}
```

another option with server option

```
//server.ts

export function redirect(
res : ServerResponse,
url: string,
statusCode = 302,
type = 'replace'
){
res.setHeader('Location', url)
res.setHeader('X-Next-Intl-Redirect', type)
res.writeHeader(statusCode )
res.end()
}
```

Comment: but this will require client components and i am using server components also server actions.

Comment: so then  fork the next-intl library and modify the redirect function to accept a type option. that the redirect functio is defined in the server.ts file. you can add a type parameter to the function sign and pass it to the res.writeHead call.

Comment: I'm not understanding your second option solution. Could you please elaborate or provide a resource?

Comment: I have added it to the my answer you can see.(edited)